# error while installing gcc on ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, installation

I recently installed Ubuntu and I want to start coding in C and C++.

I have **gdb** and **gcc** files on my desktop.

I am getting this error while trying to install the above:

```
soumya@soumya-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6-4.7-dev_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_amd64
[sudo] password for soumya: 
dpkg-split: error: error reading libstdc++6-4.7-dev_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_amd64: Is a directory
dpkg: error processing archive libstdc++6-4.7-dev_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_amd64 (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++6-4.7-dev_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_amd64
```

I have all the files on the desktop. What should I do?

Comment: What is the result if you type **gcc -v** in a terminal window in your ubuntu system ?

Answer (score 1):

In the message, we clearly see that **libstdc++6-4.7-dev_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_amd64** is a directory and not a file in your case.

So you have to provide a file.

To answer your question, when I installed Ubuntu for the first time, I found the gcc already installed

I just typed **gcc -v** and i got:

```
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
```

If for any reason you don't have access to gcc and in order to install it in ubuntu, **you will need the build-essential package**.

Build-essential contains a list of packages which are essential for building Ubuntu packages including **gcc compiler**, make and other required tools.

Just go like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Look at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers) you will get instructions to install gcc.

After doing so, you will have access to **gcc** and **g++** compilers